# equivalent to 'cpusets' for gpu's

Tags: limit, torque

I work with clusters of computers and manage the nodes with [torque](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque) and [Moab](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/hpc-products/moab-hpc-suite-enterprise-edition/).

A user is able to submit a job to a node, and request the amount of resources they need.

```
#The following submits the job foo.sh to 1 node, requesting 8 cores, and 1 gpu
qsub foo.sh -l nodes=1:ppn=8:gpus=1
```

Because it is possible for a user to take more resources than requested, I've enabled the [hwloc library](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) (cpusets) to keep users in check.

From what I have found, there is no possible way to prevent a user from taking more gpu's than they have requested.

**Is there a 'cpuset' equivalent  for gpu's?**

---

*Resources*

[Moab Documentation](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/mwm/help.htm#topics/accelerators/schedulingGpus.htm?TocPath=20.0%20Accelerators%7C_____1)

[Torque Documentation](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/commands/qsub.htm#-I)

[hwloc documentation](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/)